# Realloc is messing up the code

Tags: c

I wrote a program that's supposed to do a find and replace inside a file, with the condition that the new word must be longer than the old one. I had a lot of issues with it, like printing weird characters, or having the core dumped, but when I removed the `realloc` statement the problems seemed to go away. I'm not very familiar with the function, what mistake did I do?

Also, are my frees where they should be?

```
void replace_word(const char *s, const char *old_word, const char *new_word){
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char *init = buffer;
    FILE *original_file;
    FILE *copy;

    if((original_file = fopen(s, "r")) == NULL){
        perror(s);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((copy = fopen("copy.txt", "w")) == NULL){
        perror("text");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int old_word_len = strlen(old_word);
    int new_word_len = strlen(new_word);

    char *src;
    char *dst;
    char *tmp;
    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, original_file)){
        if((tmp = strstr(buffer, old_word))){
            buffer = realloc(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE + new_word_len - old_word_len);
            src = tmp + old_word_len;
            dst = tmp + new_word_len;
            memmove(dst, src, strlen(src));
            memcpy(tmp, new_word, new_word_len);
            buffer = init;
        }
        fprintf(copy, "%s", buffer);
        if(!strchr(buffer, '\n')){
            fseek(original_file, -old_word_len, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        free(buffer);
        buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: `src = tmp + old_word_len;` :  `tmp` point to the address is the one before `realloc`.

Comment: `memmove(dst, src, strlen(src));` --> `memmove(dst, src, strlen(src)+1);`

Comment: `buffer = init;` : `init` is old buffer.

Comment: You cannot use any pointers that pointed into the space you reallocated  (even if it happens to realloc to the same location).  It would be better to use integer offsets here.

Comment: the problem is that you're assuming that tmp is going to stay valid once you do a realloc, which it may not.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why the extra character in `memmove`?

Comment: @MichaelX It must be moved including null-terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realloc` takes a pointer to dynamically assigned memory and resizes the memory block. An important point that people less experienced with dynamic memory often miss is that the pointer returned by `realloc` may not be the same as the pointer passed in (and usually isn't). Generally, the heap does not have enough contiguous memory to do the requested expansion, so it finds a new block of memory large enough to fit it and copies the previous contents in.

The first thing I notice about your code is that you perform an unsafe `realloc`:

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE + new_word_len - old_word_len);
```

By assigning a pointer to its own `realloc`, you run the risk that the OS cannot complete the allocation and returns `NULL`. If that occurs, you've lost the pointer to your old memory and you have a memory leak on your hands. To properly `realloc` (and I'm guessing you'll need to do this anyway to fix my next point), assign the results of `realloc` to a different pointer, confirm it's not `NULL`, and then overwrite the pointer.

But I think the main problem with your code lies here:

```
buffer = init;
```

If I understand correctly, the purpose of this statement is to return `buffer` to the beginning of the string. However, the memory that `init` pointed to has been freed by the `realloc`, and you end up dereferencing the dangling pointer. You'll need to store a reference to the beginning of the new memory returned by `realloc`.

Comment: Thanks. It finally seems to work, what I did was create a second pointer inside `if` and use `malloc` instead of `realloc`, then copy the old buffer into it. I wasn't sure if realloc would expand the current block or create a new one, and the documentation wasn't clear.

Comment: That solution is probably fine. `realloc` either expands or creates a new one depending on how much contiguous memory is available at the old pointer. In the event that it has to create a new block, it copies everything in the old block to the beginning of the new block.